# Kendo Grid pagination is not working with responsive plugin footable

Tags: kendo-ui, footable

Hi I have a kendo grid which is responsive using footable plugin. It is working fine. But when i  click the pagination it is breaking the ui. Attached the image of the page. Can you pls help to fix this?

```
             @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UCM.UCW.PresentationService.Entity.Dto.Task>()
                              .Name("ValidationTaskListGrid")
                              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table-bordered" })
                              .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "footable" })
                              .Columns(columns =>
                              {
                                  columns.Bound(p => p.TaskDueDate)
                                      .Sortable(true)
                                      .Title("Due Date")
                                      .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_class = "expand" });

                                  columns.Bound(p => p.StateCode)
                                      .Sortable(true)
                                      .Title("State")
                                      .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_hide = "phone_s" });

                                  columns.Bound(p => p.DocumentType)
                                      .Sortable(true)
                                      .Title("Document Type")
                                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_hide = "phone,phone_s" });

                                  columns.Bound(p => p.Form)
                                      .Sortable(true)
                                      .Title("Form")
                                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_hide = "phone,tablet,phone_s" });

                                  columns.Bound(p => p.UnemploymentDocumentId)
                                      .Sortable(true)
                                      .Title("Document ID")
                                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_hide = "phone,tablet,phone_s" });

                                  columns.Bound(p => p.TaskSubject)
                                      .Sortable(true)
                                      .Title("Task Name ")
                                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_hide = "phone,tablet,phone_s" });

                                  columns.Bound(p => p.TaskAssignedTo)
                                      .Sortable(true)
                                      .Title("Assigned To ")
                                       .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_hide = "phone,tablet,phone_s" });

                                  columns.Bound(p => p.InstanceName)
                                      .Sortable(false)
                                      .Title("Actions")
                                      // .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_hide = "phone,phone_s" })
                                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
                                      .ClientTemplate("<a href = '" + Url.Action("GetUnemploymentDocument", "UnemploymentDocument",
                                      new { UnemploymentDocumentId = "#=UnemploymentDocumentId#", taskId = "#=TaskId#", taskAssignedToType = "#=TaskAssignedToType#" }) + "' class='btn btn-function'>Start Task</a>");


                              })

                              .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(6)
                                  .Messages(m => m.Display("Showing {0}-{1} of {2}")))
                              .Sortable(sortable => sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn).AllowUnsort(false))
                              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                  .Ajax()
                                  .Read(read => read.Action("GetValsync", "WorkList"))
                                  //.ServerOperation(WebConstants.EnableServerOperation)
                                  .ServerOperation(true)
                                  .PageSize(AppContextHelper.Instance.ApplicationConfiguration.DefaultViewItem)
                                  .Sort(sort =>
                                  {
                                      sort.Add("TaskDueDate").Descending();

                                  }))
                              .Events(x => x.DataBound("GridDataBound")

                              ))
```